# Axiom of pair follows from the weak axiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

For any x and y , if there exists z such that $x \in z \quad and \quad y \in z$

then, there exists a unique set {x,y}

Can you guys give me a hint? I don't know how to prove this..

Comment: Are there *other* axioms you can use?

Comment: I think except the axiom of pair, you can use any other axiom of Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory in here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo-Fraenkel_set_theory

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the weak axiom to deduce that there is such $z$ and then find a formula, *with parameters*, such that $\{u\in z\mid \varphi(u,x,y)\}=\{x,y\}$.